What livery is on this F-5 airframe?
Markham Airport near Toronto used to have quite a few derelict airframes sitting on the airfield, with most sporting RCAF liveries but some coming from other countries such as Belgium. There is one aircraft, however, I've always been curious about - Pictured here in a photo uploaded to Google Maps in 2011:

Where is this livery from? I don't recognize it as belonging to any air force - Was it perhaps a special demo team livery?

You can easily get the answer searching by registration number: 116703

I flew out of that airport in the mid 70s.

That is a Northrop F-5/Canadair CF-5. Owned by the RCAF.

Around 1989 the aircraft was painted in this striking 419 Squadron color scheme for air show appearances (as was CF-5A 116740)


https://www.airhistory.net/photo/478325/116703

Any idea what happened to the vertical stabilizer?  It's missing from the OP's photo.  Either that, or they are using it to demonstrate some incredible new stealth technology. Perhaps it's just more advanced than previous attempts at invisible planes? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_mrWUrMK5d4 ;)

@AmazonDiesInDarkness I was wondering about that too - Maybe the unit kept it to display when the airframe was scrapped?

@Marsroverr That's a good guess. Perhaps it is hanging on someone's garage wall.  It would make an incredible dining room table too.
